# Средний арифметический в звездном рейтинге

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток всем.Вот уже 3 дня не могу решить задачу с звездным  плагином.
Проблема состоит  в том что при клике на кнопку он показывает средний рейтинг этих 5-и чисел.Мне нужно чтобы без клика он работал.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question1').rating('create');
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#question1").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question1').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question3').rating('create');
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#question3").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question3').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question2').rating('create');
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#question2").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question2').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question4').rating('create');
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#question4").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 5,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#question4').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```css
.rating-loading {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') top left no-repeat;
  border: none;
}


/*
 * Stars
 */

.rating-fa {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-fa .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-gly {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

.rating-gly-star {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-lg .rating-gly-star,
.rating-lg .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.rating-xl .rating-gly-star,
.rating-xl .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-active {
  cursor: default;
}

.rating-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.rating-uni {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.rating-container {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e3e3e3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating-container:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}

.rating-container .rating-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container .rating-stars:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.rating-container-rtl:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #e3e3e3;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}


/**
 * Rating sizes
 */

.rating-xl {
  font-size: 4.89em;
}

.rating-lg {
  font-size: 3.91em;
}

.rating-md {
  font-size: 3.13em;
}

.rating-sm {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.rating-xs {
  font-size: 2em;
}


/**
 * Clear rating button
 */

.star-rating .clear-rating,
.star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 60%;
}

.clear-rating-active {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.clear-rating-active:hover {
  color: #843534;
}

.star-rating .clear-rating {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/**
 * Caption
 */

.star-rating .caption,
.star-rating-rtl .caption {
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 55%;
}

.star-rating .caption {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.star-rating-rtl .caption {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/**
 * Print
 */

@media print {
  .rating-container,
  .rating-container:before,
  .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars,
  .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
    color: #f3f3f3!important;
  }
  .star-rating .clear-rating,
  .star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
    display: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>


<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="rating rating-loading">
  <input id="question2">
  <input id="question3">
  <input id="question4">
</form>
<div class="entirety">
  <p class="amount">Общая оценка
    <p id='d'>0</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Нажми" onclick="try{ ww() } catch(e) {alert(e)}">
</div>


<script>
  function ww() {
    var oi = document.getElementById('fld').getElementsByTagName('input');

    var val = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < oi.length; i++) {

      val += +oi[i].value;
    };
    val = val / oi.length;
    document.getElementById('d').textContent = val;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: что-то у вас там копирайтов больше, чем кода. Добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: Вот это вот обфусцированное нечто, есть где-то на cdn? Доступно по ссылке?

Comment: [Обфускация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Обфускация&redirect=no)  Если скрипт плагина и css плагина доступны по ссылке - тогда можно было добавить сниппет в вопрос. Вставлять сюда весь плагин - вопрос слишком распухнет.

Comment: Я могу ответить, но хочу для начала привести в порядок вопрос. Хотя, как знаете...

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, речь шла про минифицированный код плагина, который в jsfiddle вставлен напрямую.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов стоит быть повежливей, когда вам хотели помочь. Вопрос закрыт, ответ на него не смогут написать, пока вопрос не будет корректно составлен. Исправляйтесь.

Comment: `я не смог полностью поставить(без минификации) код так как выводил ошибку также суда не смог вставить тоже` - поэтому вас и спросили: код чего именно там представлено? возможно где-то на cdn есть ссылка на него, чтоб можно было напрямую вставить

Comment: http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating   сслыка на сайт плагина также ссылка на гитхаб https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, суть этого сообщения как раз в том, чтобы постили не просто ссылки куда-то, а основной код приводили в вопросе.

Comment: так, подредачили сниппет корректно, переоткрыли. теперь надо с этим что-то делать)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```js
$("#question1").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars:10,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });

$('#question1').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
console.log(value);
ww();
});


  $("#question3").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 10,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });


$('#question3').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
console.log(value);
ww();
});


  $("#question2").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 10,
    min: 0,
    max:10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });


$('#question2').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
console.log(value);
ww();
});


  $("#question4").rating({
    glyphicon: true,
    stars: 10,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.5,
    showClear: true,
    size: 'xs',
    starCaptions: {
      1: 'Irrelevant',
      2: 'It Matters',
      3: 'Important',
      4: 'Very Important',
      5: 'Mandatory'
    },
    starCaptionClasses: {
      1: 'label label-info',
      2: 'label label-primary',
      3: 'label label-success',
      4: 'label label-warning',
      5: 'label label-danger'
    }
  });

$('#question4').on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
console.log(value);
ww();
});
```

```css
/*!
 * @copyright &copy; Kartik Visweswaran, Krajee.com, 2013 - 2015
 * @version 3.5.4
 *
 * A simple yet powerful JQuery star rating plugin that allows rendering
 * fractional star ratings and supports Right to Left (RTL) input.
 *
 * For more JQuery/Bootstrap plugins and demos visit http://plugins.krajee.com
 * For more Yii related demos visit http://demos.krajee.com
 */
body {
   height:1000px;
   }
.rating-loading {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') top left no-repeat;
    border: none;
}
/*
 * Stars
 */
.rating-fa {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-fa .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-gly {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

.rating-gly-star {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-lg .rating-gly-star, .rating-lg .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 4px;
}

.rating-xl .rating-gly-star, .rating-xl .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-active {
    cursor: default;
}

.rating-disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.rating-uni {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.rating-container {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rating-container:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
}

.rating-container .rating-stars {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fde16d;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container .rating-stars:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fde16d;
}

.rating-container-rtl:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #e3e3e3;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
}

/**
 * Rating sizes
 */
.rating-xl {
    font-size: 4.89em;
}

.rating-lg {
    font-size: 3.91em;
}

.rating-md {
    font-size: 3.13em;
}

.rating-sm {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}

.rating-xs {
    font-size: 2em;
}

/**
 * Clear rating button
 */
.star-rating .clear-rating, .star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 60%;
}

.clear-rating-active {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.clear-rating-active:hover {
    color: #843534;
}

.star-rating .clear-rating {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/**
 * Caption
 */
.star-rating .caption, .star-rating-rtl .caption {
    color: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 55%;
}

.star-rating .caption {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.star-rating-rtl .caption {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/**
 * Print
 */
@media print {
    .rating-container, .rating-container:before , .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars, .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
        color: #f3f3f3!important;
    }
    
    .star-rating .clear-rating, .star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>


<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="rating rating-loading">
  <input id="question2">
  <input id="question3">
  <input id="question4">
</form>
<div class="entirety">
  <p class="amount">Общая оценка
    <p id='d'>0</p>
</div>

<script>
  function ww() {
    var oi = document.getElementById('fld').getElementsByTagName('input');

    var val = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < oi.length; i++) {

      val += +oi[i].value;
    };
    val = val / oi.length;
    document.getElementById('d').textContent = val;
  }
</script>
```

Функция 'ww' должна вызыватся в каждой раз когда изменяется рейтинг и все будет работать как часы.Правда в документе это не работает на данный момент исправляю этот баг.
**Помогли называется .И суда минусов накидайте а то как же мы без этого.**

Comment: ну если ты не напишешь как именно решил проблему - то накидают

Comment: Так и совершенно правильно, что кидают. Потому что в итоге в ответе нет ответа. Просто кусок кода. А что было не так и в какую сторону копать, если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой - непонятно. Всё логично, закономерно, как я и предупреждал.

Comment: Причём тут принять не принять?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас уже используется вывод в консоль на событие изменения рейтинга.
Обработчик события `rating.change` - то самое место, которое Вам и нужно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementById('fld').getElementsByTagName('input');

  function ww() {
    var val = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      val += +inputs[i].value;
    };
    val = val / inputs.length;
    document.getElementById('d').textContent = val;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];

    $(input).rating('create');

    $(input).rating({
      glyphicon: true,
      stars: 5,
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      step: 1,
      showClear: true,
      size: 'xs',
      starCaptions: {
        1: 'Irrelevant',
        2: 'It Matters',
        3: 'Important',
        4: 'Very Important',
        5: 'Mandatory'
      },
      starCaptionClasses: {
        1: 'label label-info',
        2: 'label label-primary',
        3: 'label label-success',
        4: 'label label-warning',
        5: 'label label-danger'
      }
    });

    $(input).on('rating.change', function(event, value) {
      console.log(value);
      ww(); // <-- Вызываем пересчёт
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.rating-loading {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  background: transparent url('../img/loading.gif') top left no-repeat;
  border: none;
}


/*
 * Stars
 */

.rating-fa {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-fa .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 1px;
}

.rating-gly {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}

.rating-gly-star {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-lg .rating-gly-star,
.rating-lg .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.rating-xl .rating-gly-star,
.rating-xl .rating-gly-star .rating-stars:before {
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.rating-active {
  cursor: default;
}

.rating-disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.rating-uni {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.rating-container {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e3e3e3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating-container:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}

.rating-container .rating-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container .rating-stars:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.rating-container-rtl:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #e3e3e3;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

.rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}


/**
 * Rating sizes
 */

.rating-xl {
  font-size: 4.89em;
}

.rating-lg {
  font-size: 3.91em;
}

.rating-md {
  font-size: 3.13em;
}

.rating-sm {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.rating-xs {
  font-size: 2em;
}


/**
 * Clear rating button
 */

.star-rating .clear-rating,
.star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 60%;
}

.clear-rating-active {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

.clear-rating-active:hover {
  color: #843534;
}

.star-rating .clear-rating {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/**
 * Caption
 */

.star-rating .caption,
.star-rating-rtl .caption {
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 55%;
}

.star-rating .caption {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.star-rating-rtl .caption {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/**
 * Print
 */

@media print {
  .rating-container,
  .rating-container:before,
  .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars,
  .rating-container-rtl .rating-stars:before {
    color: #f3f3f3!important;
  }
  .star-rating .clear-rating,
  .star-rating-rtl .clear-rating {
    display: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/css/star-rating.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/v3.5.4/js/star-rating.js"></script>


<form id="fld">
  <input id="question1" class="rating rating-loading">
  <input id="question2">
  <input id="question3">
  <input id="question4">
</form>
<div class="entirety">
  <p class="amount">Общая оценка
    <p id='d'>0</p>
</div>
```

---

*Помимо прочего, я немного отрефакторил инициализацию полей, на предмет DRY*

Comment: Какого рода проблема? В чём заключается интеграция?

Comment: Но разве сниппет в ответе не работает? И счётчик среднего обновляется, и звёзды показываются...

Comment: Разве это проблема кода в ответе?

Comment: А у меня и документа-то нет :( Как же он у меня в нём работать будет?